# How to identify non-matching elements in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Given there is a huge set of elements (e.g. a list of IDs).

```
$setOfIds = $externalSource->getElementsIds();
// gives sth. like => $setOfIds = ['1b23', '2c18', 'h23a', …];
```

Given there is a function that determines if the complete set or any given subset matches certain search criteria but does not identify specific elements that don't match the criteria (i.e. by a database query on the set).

```
$database->hasIds($setOfIds); // returns true if all ids given with the set are found in database
```

How to identify the elements, that match search criteria without looping the whole set.

```
$missingIds = findMissing($setOfIds); // how would findMissing() be implemented?
```

Given there is no element with id `h23a` in the database but in `$setOfIds` and `$setOfIds` does contain hundreds or thousands of ids which all are to be found in the database, the result of running the to-be-implemented method should resolve to

```
$missingIds == ['h23a'];
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a clear example of what the inputs would be and what the output would be, at the moment it seems unclear what you are trying to achieve (IMHO) apart from answering your own question.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a generic way with a recursive function similar to git's [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) or a binary search that applies the given check-function to a left and a right part of the set of elements.

```
/**
 * Recursively searches for elements in $elements that match search-critearia checked by $callback
 * Inspects two halfs of an array with itself if check-function return false on complete set of elements
 *
 * @param array    $elements the set of elements to check
 * @param callable $callback pass a function that checks the set and returns true if search criteria apply, false else
 *
 * @return array   list of elements that match the criteria checked by callback
 */
function bisect(array $elements, callable $callback) : array {
    // $elements is an empty array at the end of the recursion, when the remaining 1-sized set of element was sliced
    // when the complete matches the criteria checked by $callback, there is no need for further recursion
    if (empty($elements) || false === $callback($elements)) {
        return [];
    }

    // set only has one remaining element and callback returned false on it => identified an element that matches criteria
    if (1 === count($elements)) {
        return $elements;
    }

    $sectionSize = count($elements)/2; 
    $left = array_slice($elements, 0, $sectionSize);
    $right = array_slice($elements, $sectionSize);

    return array_merge(bisect($left, $callback), bisect($right, $callback));
}
```

Given the data from the question the elements can be identified like this:

```
$missingIds = bisect(
   $setOfIds,
   function ($ids) use ($database) { return !$database->hasIds($ids); }
);
```